# How to place EditText over a button when in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

What I want it to look like:

[image]

I want to have a text box that is inside of the button (where the time goes) that is editable. How do I do this?

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    // NAME 1
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:text="Name"
        android:onClick="changeName"/>
    // NAME 2
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:onClick="changeName"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks, and sorry for the simplicity of the question. I'm just an amateur trying to learn more.

Comment: you don't need a text box, append time along with a '\n' to text of button, so that it comes below the text

Comment: placing content over another is not possible in Linear Layout. Use Relative Layout instead

Comment: @VivekMishra ever heard of FrameLayout? this is what basically the whole layout about.

Comment: @k0sh I know about Frame Layout but what is the problem in using Relative Layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way it will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f8f0"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#4472C4"
            >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Liam Ten"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="01:03:66"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Neil C"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#4472C4"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are showing timer's time which is going to change frequently. Better use this approach.

```
String myValue = String.format("%s \n %s", "Liam Tan" , String.valueOf(yourTimingValue));

myButton.setText(myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are two ways to achieve this.

```
name1.setText("Liam Taen" + "\n" + dateTimeString);
```

and in xml add `multiline=true` to Button name1

Secondly, use

```
<LinearLayout root layout with orientation horizontal
  <LinearLayout width weight 1 where orientation vertical
     <Button  for name >
     <TextView for showing time>
  </LinearLayout end linearLayout>

  <LinearLayout width weight 1 where orientation vertical>
       <Button name2 to center by layout_gravity= center or gravity= center from parent
  </LinearLayout end second linearlayout>

</LinearLayout end root  linearlayout>
```